# Git - Extract sub-directory to a new repository while tracking old remote

Tags: git, github

I have this file structure that is tracked in a remote (let's call it `original remote`) :

```
root
  folderX
  manyOtherFolders
```

**I would like to:**

1. move `folderX` to a new repo with a new remote
2. The new repo should be able to pull new code from '*original remote*'
3. Note: Many files in the `new repo` will change location

**Steps I have in mind:**

- `git clone original repo`
- `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter folderX master`
- create new **remote** repo on hosting service
- add the new remote to the new local repo

What would be the best way to approach this task?

Comment: You could use git submodules here, but I don't get why both remotes need to add changes to this folder. Could you give more details on why you need this approach?

Comment: Hi @TheGeorgeous
Extracting this folder to a separate repo will take a while due to high complexity.
Meanwhile, new code is pushed to `old origin` so the new repo needs to be in sync so it can be deployed sometime in the future with no rollbacks.

Comment: You could make the separation first and prepare the new repo for deployment. Once all the checks are done, you could perform the same steps again and force push the new changes instead to the new repo.

Comment: I've applied the steps you listed successfully before to split 30 sub-folders into their own repositories.. The final step i did which is missing from your list is push the new branch you've created with `filter-branch` to the new remote (i didn't have either of these locally yet). But, this new repository has a unrelated history to the original. All the tree-objects in the .git database now look different, path wise. I'm note sure tracking sub-folders from other remotes is possible.